# volume shrink process interrupted

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I have 2TB expansion disk which is partitioned into two volumes. In the second volume I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.
The first partition is formatted as NTFS logical volume and I use it to save files.

I wanted to shrink first volume in order to merge the space with contiguous Ext4 partition.

I used `gpated` and shrinked it about 100GB, I applied it, it started the process to take about 24 hours. 
But computer froze and I had to do hard boot.
It booted up well, I checked out the first partition, the files present.
Volume looks shrinked but since it failed during transfering files I fear that something is wrong.
What should I do now to complete the process?

EDIT: I get the following warning:

```
Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs.
```

EDIT2: I made a mistake, I heedlessly run `ls . >backup.txt` to save the list of files in the root directory of `NTFS`. I inserted expansion disk to a Windows PC, it asked for my permission to fix the filesystem, after a while it fixed the filesystem. I found a directory named `found.000`. It contains around two thousand files. 
I am still suspicious about integrity of the files after I ignorantly created `backup.txt` file. I fear that some files are overwritten by that file.

Comment: All NTFS partitions should be managed and resized via Windows Disk Manager. Try booting into Windows and run `chkdsk` on the NTFS partition. ps: no way should it have taken 24 hours...

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for responding. You are right, it must be `NTFS` issue, because whenever I move files from `Ext4` to `NTFS` transfer rate slows down and hangs. 
What I need to learn, how can I fix `NTFS` volume? Could some data be left on newly created unallocated space?

Comment: Did you install `ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs`? NTFS volumes can really only be fixed by using `chkdsk` in Windows. You're disk may still be messed up due to the failure mode. I'd also run `fsck` on the ext4 partition (sudo fsck -f /dev/sdxx).

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I installed them long ago. I did the most stupid thing a few minutes ago, while moving files to `Ext4` I happened to create 227 byte long text file to list files in one of the directories with  `ls . >backup.txt`.